# How to repaint JPanel from outside its parent JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I can add/remove elements to/from a `panel` and repaint it when the method used to fill the panel is called by one of its parent JFrame events, but I can not repaint it by events from other classes even if their sources have been added to it, or that is how I understand the problem for now.

I want to understand what is going on here, Thank you.

**Main Class**

```
public class Principal extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
private static Principal instPrincipal = null;    
private SubClass subClassInst =new SubClass();
public JPanel panelPrincipal;

public static Principal getInstance() {
    if (instPrincipal != null)
        return instPrincipal ;
    else {
        instPrincipal = new Principal ();
        return instPrincipal ;
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    Object source = event.getSource();
    try {
        if(source == btnSub)
        {
          subClassInst.fillPanelPrincipal();
        }
        }
     catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
 }
```

**Sub Classes Example**

```
public class SubClass implements ActionListener {

private JPanel tempPanel;
private JButton btnSave; 
private Principal instPrincipal; 

public void fillPanelPrincipal() {
    instPrincipal = Principal.getInstance();
    instPrincipal.panelPrincipal.removeAll();
    //Start adding elements..
    tempPanel = new JPanel();
    instPrincipal.panelPrincipal.add(tempPanel);
    btnSave = new JButton("Save");
    btnSave.addActionListener(this);
    tempPanel.add(btnSave);
    //End. 
    instPrincipal.panelPrincipal.repaint();
  }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    instPrincipal = Principal.getInstance();
    Object source = event.getSource();
    if (source == btnSave) {
    // modify local data, Database .. ; //work but need to be repainted on panelPrincipal
    instPrincipal.panelPrincipal.repaint();//does not work
    }
   }

}
```

**Update**

To clarify the problem more, I have one single `JPanel` on a `JFrame` and there are different classes to fill it for multiple functionalities, I call their methods using `JMenuItems` on the main frame, these Classes implement `ActionListener`, passing the panel didn't work, and also the method I am trying here.
I thought about changing the design to use `CardLayout`, but it was very difficult.

Comment: You shouldn't  declare your JPanel as `static`.

Comment: @user3437460 Static is not the issue here, it just means the same for all objects of the class, and for you I made a test without it,  but no change. Thank you.

Comment: This `public static JPanel panelPrincipal;` is so massive dangerous. You literally have no control over how this value is changed by other class, not can you guarantee that the value you are referencing is actually the value on the screen.  Used in this way is a very good indication of a bad design.  Also, based on the use of `setBounds`, it would suggest that you are not using a layout manager, which means `revalidate` is pointless and which could be another indiciator of potional issues

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @TiyebBellal I am not saying making your JPanel will magically make everything works and it never will. I said you shouldn't make your panel as static because you ***don't have to*** and there are many undesirable issues you will get yourself into for doing so.

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer for `revalidate` note, you were right.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling Principal as a static reference, so how is it supposed to know what frame to repaint? You should pass the instance of the JFrame through the constructor of the subclass. Like so:

```
private SubClass subClassInst = new SubClass(this);
```

And create the constructor like this

```
private JFrame parent;
public SubClass(JFrame parent) { this.parent = parent; }
```

You can then use it like so

```
this.parent.repaint();
```

Comment: I have passed the JFrame as param as you suggested but this is not the problem, Thank you.